# How should I increase max_locks_per_transaction in PostgreSQLContainer while doing integration test

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Currently my code looks like below:

```java
private static final String IMAGE_VERSION =
        "postgres:permanent-13.2";

    private static TestPostgresContainer container;

    private TestPostgresContainer() {
        super(DockerImageName.parse(IMAGE_VERSION).asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres"));
        withInitScript("setup/main.sql");
        withDatabaseName("test");
        withUsername("postgres");
        withPassword("postgres");
        withUrlParam("currentSchema", "testSchema");
    }

public static TestPostgresContainer getInstance() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new TestPostgresContainer();
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", container.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // do nothing.
    }
```

Whenever I run my integration test using SQL queries I get below error:

**org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement**
**Hint: You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.**

I can change the config locally in postgres.conf but the problem is while initializing the test container and the test also runs under jenkins.